# Multimeter measuring different values on different probe polarities?

Tags: current, multimeter

I have a UNI-T UT33A+ model multimeter and I'm using it to read current values for my assignments. The weird thing is I get entirely different values when I switch probe positions. For example when I measure black to red I'm getting -0.80mA, and 0.42mA when I measure red to black. What can be the cause of this?

The fullscale accuracy according to the manual is $$\pm(1.0\%+2)$$ for 20 mA.

Comment: Sounds like a -0.2mA offset current : what does the spec say is the DC accuracy?

Comment: +-(1.0% + 2) accuracy according to the manual.

Comment: If that means +/-1% of full scale then it's well within spec : if it's +/-1% of reading, then ... not.

Comment: [Image Link](https://imgur.com/a/m6RHNvN) Here's the manual image. Sorry I'm not good at reading manuals just yet. @Brian Drummond

Comment: In my experience, Uni-T is pretty garbage as multimeters go. If you can't afford a Fluke or Keysight meter, do a little research; I think some of the FLIR/Extech ones are pretty good.